# for each checkbox in the table, if checkbox is selected, apply class to td tag,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I have a table and each row contains a checkbox.

When a checkbox is selected, I want to call a JavaScript function. I'd like to be advised how this would work, for example, If I click the checkbox on the second row of the table, it calls a javascript function and applies a class to the td tag.

This is my table ...

```
     while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                echo "<tr id='request-$row->ar_Id'>";
                echo "<td id='request-checked'><input type='checkbox'  id='chk-appRequest' onchange='flagRequestAsSelected()'></span></td>";
                echo '<td>' . $row->ar_Id . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->ar_patientId . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->pd_forename . ' ' . $row->pd_lastname . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->ar_appointmentTime . '</td>';
                echo '<td id="requestedDate">' . $row->ar_appointmentDate . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row->ar_doctorId . '</td>';
                echo '<td id="alternativeAptTime" aria-hidden="true">' . $row->ar_alternativeTime . '</td>';
                echo '<td id="alternativeAptDate" aria-hidden="true">' . $row->ar_alternativeDate . '</td>';
                echo '<td id="alternativeAptDoctor" aria-hidden="true">' . $row->ar_alternativeDoctor . '</td>';
                echo '<td id="bookedBit" aria-hidden="true">' . $row->ar_booked . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
```

JavaScript -

```
  function flagRequestAsSelected()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("tbl-appointment-requests");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

                'How to check if checkbox is checked???

                if (.checked == true)
                {
                    col.innerHTML = "BLAH";
                }
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Need clarification. You can always call `onChange="flagRequestAsSelected(this)"` and then you will have access to the clicked input in your function, but you didn't say what you want to do.

Comment: @AvAvt If a checkbox is selected (on any row) it then calls 'flagRequestAsSelected'. I need advise on how I can this working for each row in the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JQuery to check a checkbox in a parent list-item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600422/use-jquery-to-check-a-checkbox-in-a-parent-list-item)

Comment: @Xavjer No duplication here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just edit your question, hope my new answer will help you.

So change your html for

```
<input type='checkbox'  id='chk-appRequest' onchange='flagRequestAsSelected(this)'> 
<!-- I added (this) inside your function parameters list -->
```

And edit your JS for

```
function flagRequestAsSelected(obj){ // I added obj param
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl-appointment-requests");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

            //How to check if checkbox is checked???

            if (obj.checked == true){ // Check if the returned object is checked
                col.innerHTML = "BLAH";
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

OLD ANSWER :

With jQuery you can do this

```
$(".myInputClass").on("change", function() { 
    console.log("this change!");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("myClass"); // Add class to the td parent
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it will only work for the first row in the table.

Comment: put a class in your inputs then, and change $("#chk-appRequest") for $(".myClass")

Comment: This still doesn't do the job.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope this gives a clearer idea of what i want.

Comment: I've added my javascript to the post, do you know how I can access the input element of the td tag to then alter the inner html (eventually, i will be applying a class to the td tag).

Comment: New answer : If my answer didn't help you, it may be because it's not clear what you really want to do.